# subdomain like setup using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting, subdomain

I need a help regarding htaccess. I need a subdomain like setup using htaccess. It should redirect or show the contents from one of my controllers.

For eg:

I have a controller say "view" and method called "site". i would pass some parameters

Current url will be: `www.mydomain.com/view/site/name`

Now what i need is i should have a setup like following

`name.mydomain.com  =   www.mydomain.com/view/site/name`

my current htaccess looks like this

```
allow from all

Options -Multiviews

RewriteEngine On

Options -Multiviews

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-l

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?rt=$1 [L,QSA]
```

what should i add to it? Please let me know

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off - You do not need to repeat `Options -Multiviews`

And as for the rule

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.mydomain\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mydomain.com/view/site/%1/$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

the `%` says: *take first parameter from the RewriteCond* as it starts with `%{HTTP_HOST}`

the `$` says: *take first parameter from the RewriteRule*